# Django Querysets: Ordering posts by number of similar tags

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a Django model for :

Post - Representing a blog post
Tag - Representing a canonical Tag. Let's pretend it's a hashtag.
PostTag - A foreign key intermediary between Posts and Tags.

Now let's say I have 5 posts with these tags:

1. #food #story #recepie #gardening #entree
2. #food #story #recepie #ham # sandwich
3. #food #story #flowers #fish #sushi
4. #food #story #computer #keyboard #mouse
5. #food #coffee #vitamins #basil #citrus

--

Given Post 1 with it's 5 tags, how can I get N number of other posts with the most similar tags?

```
Posts.objects.filter(publish_at__gte=somedatetime).order_by("similarity")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) each `Post` with a [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) of its tags that match the current post. You can then sort using that annotated field.

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Q

post = Post.objects.first()

similar_posts = Post.objects.filter().annotate(
    similar_tags=Count('tags', filter=Q(tags__in=post.tags.all()))
).order_by('-similar_tags')[:5]
```

Adding a slice `[:5]` adds a `LIMIT 5` to the query (if we're only interested in the 5 most similar posts).

This example is based off a simple model definition:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('PostTag')


class PostTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: The filter(=Q(tags__in=post.tags.all())) will filter all posts that have tags in common with the current post; however, wouldn't all these filtered posts will ALSO retain their unrelated tags? So when you count the 'tags', wouldn't you end up counting all of their tags? For e.g., in the examples from OP, if we are trying to find posts similar to post 1, and by the above Q filter, post 2 gets filtered, wouldn't the filtered post also retain #ham # sandwich (which are not present in Post 1)?

Comment: @Rishi The question asked how to construct a _query_ that retrieves "N number of other posts with the most similar tags". The code in my answer does exactly what the question asked for, and I tested it with their examples - it annotates each post with a numerical count of similar tags so that a sort can be applied to the query. The question did not ask how to ensure that a set of filtered tags are accessible in each individual object (which is what you're asking about). It's not difficult to implement, but the question didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions might be writing custom ModelManager which filters other posts using `difflib.get_close_matches()` (you would need to cast to string list or sth  similar)

Or maybe simpler solution but I am not sure you would get what you need; filter with the use of `icontains` in "Q" objects in Django and combine them.

Comment: Any idea how other services do this right now? Seems like a fairly well understood / solved problem but these seem a bit like hacks. One other option is to run a calculated computation for every post, but that also seems a bit crazy on a large social network.

Comment: I don't think there is easy solution without using some ML. Tags are many to many relations in database to the Post and not CharField or TextField as # separated  words. You would need to combine at least queries for hashtag A and hashtag B as inclusive set so you can find which posts have given tags.

Comment: But that requires a lot of queries. And I think the standard solution would be something with the use of ElasticSearch

Comment: Sorry If that didn't help you ! :C